# activerecord-postgres-hstore after save error ordering in Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, serialization, rails-activerecord, hstore

**store as Hash Table with Hstore, wrong ordering in Hash after Save**

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :properties, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore
end

service = Service.new
service.properties = { "aaa" => 1, "zz" => 2, "cc" => 3, "d" => 4 }
#=> { "aaa" => 1, "zz" => 2, "cc" => 3, "d" => 4 }
service.save
reload!
service = Service.find(:id)
service.properties
#=> { "d" => "4", "cc" => "3", "zz" => 2, "aaa" => 1 }
Bug::: wrong ordering after save
```

Is it because after serialize that it orders by Tree. Any ideas or anyone had faced this problem before? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [fine PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html):

> **F.16. hstore**
>   [...]
>   This module implements the hstore data type for storing sets of key/value pairs within a single PostgreSQL value.
>   [...]
>   The order of the pairs is not significant (and may not be reproduced on output).

So PostgreSQL's hstore type is an unordered set of key/value pairs that doesn't guarantee any particular order of the key/value pairs. Once your Ruby Hash is converted to an hstore, the ordering is lost.

If you need to maintain the order in your Hash you'll have to use a different serialize format.

Comment: I was trying to use Hstore to store custom header/values for a csv I was creating. However after reading this I decided to store them in 2 separate arrays instead.